# Why do I have to click the button more than once? tkinter gui

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I have created a GUI using tkinter, it accepts entry from users.
I have created my own presence checks and 'spelling' checks to ensure that the user only enters accepted values. 
But each time that I enter these values it makes the user click on the submit button multiple times before the output screen comes up. 
Is this because I have used multiple functions? 
Are there any other ways to do this?

```
def Search():
    global E1, E2, E3, E4, file

    def PresenceValidation():

        if E1.get() ==(''):
            root2=Tk()
            errortext = Label(root2, text = "Please enter eye colour")  
            errortext.pack()
        elif E2.get() ==(''):
            root2=Tk()
            root2.configure(bg="white")
            errortext = Label(root2, text = "Please enter age")
            errortext.pack()
        elif E3.get() ==(''):
            root2=Tk()
            root2.configure(bg="white")
            errortext = Label(root2, text = "Please enter hair colour")
            errortext.pack()
        elif E4.get() ==(''):
            root2=Tk()
            root2.configure(bg="white")
            errortext = Label(root2, text = "Please enter shoesize")
            errortext.pack()            
        else:
            button = Button(root, text = "Submit information", command=SpellCheck)
            button.grid(row=3, column=2, padx = 5)

    def SpellCheck():
        if E1.get().lower() not in ('blue', 'brown', 'green'):
            root2=Tk()
            root2.configure(bg="white")
            errortext = Label(root2, text = "Please enter eye colour")
            message= Label(root2, text = "Blue, Brown or Green")
            errortext.pack()
            message.pack()
        elif E2.get().lower()  not in ('10-20', '20-30', '30-40','40+'):
            root2=Tk()
            root2.configure(bg="white")
            errortext = Label(root2, text = "Please enter a valid age group")
            message=Label(root2, text = "10-20, 20-30, 30-40 or 40+")
            errortext.pack()
            message.pack()
        elif E3.get().lower()  not in ('Brown', 'Black', 'Blonde', 'Auburn'):
            root2=Tk()
            root2.configure(bg="white")
            errortext = Label(root2, text = "Please enter a valid hair colour")
            message = Label(root2, text = "Brown, Black, Blonde or Auburn")
            errortext.pack()
            message.pack()
        elif E4.get().lower() not in ('1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8+'):
            root2=Tk()
            root2.configure(bg="white")
            errortext = Label(root2, text = "Please enter a valid shoesize")
            message = Label(root2, text = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8+")
            errortext.pack()
            message.pack()         
        else:
            submitbutton = Button(window, text = "Submit information", command=Submit)
            submitbutton.grid(row=3, column=2, padx = 5)   


    root = Tk()
    root.title ("Search for matches")



    #text that will be shown to the user
    root.configure(bg="white")
    Label(root, text="Please enter eye colour").grid(row=0)
    Label(root, text="Please enter age").grid(row=1)
    Label(root, text="Please enter hair colour").grid(row=2)
    Label(root, text="Please enter shoesize").grid(row=3)


    #Create user entry points
    E1= Entry(root)
    E2= Entry(root)
    E3= Entry(root)
    E4= Entry(root)
    # locating input boxes to area on the screen
    E1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    E2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    E3.grid(row=2, column=1)
    E4.grid(row=3, column=1)




    submitbutton = Button(window, text = "Submit information", command=PresenceValidation)
    submitbutton.grid(row=3, column=2, padx = 5)

    def Quit():
    window.destroy()

    quitbton = Button (window, text ="QUIT", command=Quit)
    quitbton.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5)
```

Comment: you have 2 buttons with exact same text `Submit information` & location & even the `submitbutton` variable

Comment: thats because they all lead to the same output function

Comment: the thing is they are at exact same location.so they are overlapping each other. right now you must be having to have to press the button twice due to this

Comment: atleast change the row or column

Comment: sorry **thrice** (i counted them wrong :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this to omit a lot of the code and still have it function the way you want it. The reason you're getting multiple buttons is because you're making multiple buttons. Three of them, if I counted them all. The initial `Submit` button should call a function that validates the fields and breaks out of the loop if it runs across an incorrect value. You can also use a [Messagebox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm) to prompt the user where the error is.

And if you don't add the Messagebox and want to keep it as is, you should change the root2 instance to a Toplevel widget to avoid creating two instances of Tkinter. This could also cause unintended results.

Here's an example of how simple you could make your presence check:

```
from tkMessageBox import showwarning

def PresenceValidation():
    #Make dictionary to hold values
    values = {'Eye color': E1.get(),
              'Age': E2.get(),
              'Hair': E3.get(),
              'Shoesize': E4.get()
              }

    #Iterate over dictionary to check for empty items
    for k,v in values.iteritems():
        if v == '':
            showwarning('Empty Value Alert',    #Create alert message
                        k + ' needs a value')   #for the first empty value,
            break                               #and break out of the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you are creating more than one root window. Tkinter isn't designed to work that way. If you need more windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.